# SQL Query with and without inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to do an equi join in the from clause or where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694281/is-it-better-to-do-an-equi-join-in-the-from-clause-or-where-clause)

I'm a noob in SQL,i have 2 queries:

```
SELECT 
    A.COLUMN1,B.COLUMN2, C.COLUMN3
FROM
     TB_ITEM A,
     TB_ITEM_CAT B,
     TB_ITEM_SUBCAT C
WHERE
     A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN1
     AND A.COLUMN1 = c.COLUMN1
```

and

```
SELECT 
    A.COLUMN1,B.COLUMN2, C.COLUMN3
FROM
     TB_ITEM A 
INNER JOIN TB_ITEM_CAT B on A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN1
INNER JOIN TB_ITEM_SUBCAT C on A.COLUMN1 = C.COLUMN1
```

In first query,we dont have INNER JOINS,and select from 3 tables.
In the second,we have the same query with INNER JOINS,and select from 3 tables.

They are supposed to show same result?
What the difference beetween these queries?

Comment: ANSI-89 vs ANSI-92. No difference in performance. See [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: Are you seeing any difference in the results? I would expect them to be identical. This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686190/mysql-query-perfomance-which-one-is-best , although that was specifically concerned with performance on MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are semantically the same. A decent optimizer will recognize this an generate equally efficient plans. An experienced SQL coder will also recognize this ;)

Joe Celko quote, "There are at least seven ways to write a query; only two are worth
using."

Answer (score 2):

The first query *does* have inner joins. In the FROM clause, commas are shorthand for INNER JOIN.

Comment: The question is whether it's joining correctly.

Comment: hum,and if it hadn't commas?Would be the same?

Answer (score 0):

well,

I think the result is the same. But, when your SQL is very large, using INNER JOIN will help you organize the query.