# inner join SQL in Visual Studio

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to inner join two tables from access, but I am having trouble summarizing information from the second table. What is the proper syntax for averages within a query when using inner join?

Comment: Please show us the query/code you currently have.

Comment: Dim StudentDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select major, studstanding, from students inner join MIS on students.studentID = MIS.studentID ", StudentDataConnection)

Comment: Please post your table schema.

Comment: I want an average from my MIS table of a particular column but I have no idea where the code for the average command should be placed.

Comment: What exactly should a table schema include? Column headings of the original table(s) or from the desired output?

Comment: more on inner joins : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394853/sql-inner-join-syntax

Comment: Show us the columns of the tables involved, along with ideally some sample input and output.  If you do this, you will quickly get an answer.  Please update soon before you are voted off.

Comment: From Students: Major, StudentStanding; From MIS: quiz1, quiz2, quiz3 joined with studentID. I need averages for the different quizzes, but not sure where in the query to include the code.

Comment: Please do not add relevant information in comments. **Edit** your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

This will return an average:

```
SELECT      Students.StudentID, 
            AVG(quiz1) AS AverageOfQuiz1,
            AVG(quiz2) AS AverageOfQuiz2,
            AVG(quiz3) AS AverageOfQuiz3
FROM        Students INNER JOIN MIS ON Students.StudentID = MIS.StudentID
GROUP BY    Students.StudentID
```