# Inner join, sql confused

Tags: mysql

This is the challeng for my class. 
Using INNER JOIN retrieve the following information:

1. Using the customers and orders table find all the orders that were created by an owner of a company.

I came up with this but when I enter it it says empty set>>>

```
SELECT id FROM orders INNER JOIN customers USING (id);
```

These are the columns from the customers table.
CUSTOMERS

```
 | id   | company | last_name | first_name  | email_address | job_title       
 | business_phone  | home_phone | mobile_phone | fax_number | address 
 | city | state_province  |  zip_postal_code |  country_region  | web_page    
 | notes | attachments |.
```

These are the columns from the orders table.
ORDERS

```
| id  | employee_id | customer_id | order_date | shipped_date | shipper_id           
| ship_name | ship_address | ship_city | ship_state_province  
| ship_zip_postal_code  | ship_country_region  | shipping_fee | taxes                
| payment_type | paid_date | notes | tax_rate | tax_status_id | status_id
```

Comment: No one is going to read that.  Format properly.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You seem to be matching order ID to customer ID..

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query, and don't include plainly irrelevant columns

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
SELECT id FROM orders INNER JOIN customers USING (id);
```

you are requesting:

```
SELECT o.ID              -- or c.ID
  FROM Orders AS o
  JOIN Customers AS c
    ON O.ID = C.ID;
```

You're asking "which customers have an ID that is the same as an order ID?", which is probably not what you meant.

Most likely, you want to use some variant of:

```
SELECT o.ID AS Order_ID, c.ID AS Customer_ID
  FROM Orders AS o
  JOIN Customers AS c
    ON O.Customer_ID = C.ID;
```

You get to choose what information you get in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of inner join syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394853/sql-inner-join-syntax). Here is one example of how to do this:

```
select o.* 
from orders o
inner join customers c on o.customer_id = c.id
/* not sure how "owner of company" is represented in the data, but I'm assuming it's some value for job_title */
where c.job_title = 'owner'
```

Comment: What do the o and the c refer to?

Comment: They are table aliases. It just makes it easier to reference the tables in the join criteria so you don’t need to put `orders.customer_id = customers.id`.

Comment: @ryanc true, but it's not *just* for that

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, my “just” simply referred to the limits of their purpose in my example. I don’t think it would have been helpful to this user at this stage in their learning to describe joining to the same table multiple times or other similar purposes.